# ajax success call back function was not called when the dataType is JSONP.in Cross domain Access

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

```
type = 'calci';
var ajurl = "example.com&callback=mycallback";
var datas = "cateid=" + cateid + "&type=" + type + "&pno=" + pno + "&whos=" + whos;
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: ajurl,
  data: datas,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: 'callback',
  username: "abcdxyz",
  password: "lkjljlmkjhlkj",
  success: function(data) {
    alert('success...');
    console.log(data);
  },
  jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError);
  }
});
```

i have defined call back function

```
function mycallback(jsondata){
  console.log(jsondata+"CHeck");
  $('#calcilist').html(jsondata);
}
```

If i print error its shows either call back function was not defined or queryasjdkbaskjds1298372981379284-2132 is not called.

Answer (score 0):

from url try change `&callback=mycallback` to `&callback=?` or remove it and change from

```
jsonp: 'callback',
```

to

```
jsonp: false,
```